# Offline Cross platform speech to text using Xamarin for Smart Phones

Tags: c#, android, ios, windows, xamarin

Is it possible to have a common library for Offline cross platform Speech to text conversion and have shared code to run on all devices

I have already created an application for Offline Android speech to text using

(Pocketsphinx on Android)
 http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid 
and For Windows(Microsoft Speech )
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh361618(v=office.14).aspx

but i want to have a shared code for all these devices

Thanks 
Hassan

Comment: You could be the lucky guy to write that plugin. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/nuget/